# Wifi Problem Ubuntu 18.04. LTS HP Stream 13-c00

Tags: networking, wireless, hp

I just changed to Ubuntu 18.04.LTS from windows 10 Because my PC was running very slow

But I decided to do it completely so (when installing the SO) decided to erase windows and install ubuntu.

Please have in count that my english is bad AF, and that I'm actually really bad with computers in general

Take in count that my pc doesn't have a **wire internet port** so i can only access through wifi (which in this case doesn't work)

If your solution implies using the Terminal please write step by step what to put into the terminal so I can do it like a monkey

Please, if you guys need any more information just ask I'll edit this post and put everything you ask.

[Here's my pc's information](https://support.hp.com/gb-en/document/c04542594)

[Here's a photo of the wifi screen](https://gyazo.com/1b74b15cdfdc507798dcbfcee351dd8f)

Answer (score 1):

In case if you have smart phone just try to connect using usb tethering and follow the steps below:

- Open Terminal and update the apt repository using this command `sudo apt update`
- Now Open Software & Update
- Navigate to Additional Drivers where you can see something like in the below screenshot
- If you able to have this then click on something like **using Broadcom 802.11** and then click on apply changes. After successful installation you will see wifi on the right hand corner of your screen.
- You are good to go with your wifi

**Note:** If you have any doubts or issues please update your question accordingly and add error messages screenshots if available.

Happy Ubuntu :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try tethering from your phone via USB or, if you're lucky enough, via Bluetooth (this is different across phones, so you'll have to figure it our by yourself). If you can't, get a USB Wi-Fi adapter compatible with Ubuntu (and you may not need to complete the steps below unless you really want to).

Next, run this command that will show your networking card:

```
lspci | grep Network
```

On my HP laptop, it prints:

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device d723
```

If you have Realtek as I do, do this (I use [this driver](https://github.com/smlinux/rtl8723de), works well for me):

1. Install `git` and `dkms` (you'll need these to install the driver) with `sudo apt install git dkms` (it will ask for your password to install the packages).
2. Run `git clone https://github.com/smlinux/rtl8723de.git -b 4.15-up`. Note that it will create a new directory in the current directory and download the driver's source code into that directory.
3. Run `dkms add ./rtl8723de`.
4. Run `sudo dkms install rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414` (this command compiles the driver and installs it into the kernel, and the latter step requires root).
5. Run `sudo depmod -a`.
6. Reboot.